# 7-Zip Decompress of Many Small Files Slow

Tags: windows, compression, 7zip

We're distributing software which involves decompressing an archive of almost a million small (approx 1K) files on Windows (typically Windows 11). I've noticed that although some of the more exotic implementations of 7-Zip (e.g. Lizard/LZ5 compression) do an admirable job of compressing up the files (approx 2 min) into an archive, the corresponding decompress takes about six times as long, and appears to be independent of the actual compression method used. Also, at no point does either the disk or the CPU come close to full utilization (30% of each is typical).

I've tried disabling Windows Defender, any other running programs, and Task Manager isn't showing anything interesting going on. Is this underwhelming performance simply a factor of file creation in Windows 11? Anything else I can check?

Thanks!
-Pete

Comment: How many parallel processes did you start?

Comment: Tried mmt=32 but the expand didn't accept it. As such, whatever the default is.

Comment: What ist your whole script? Did you try using multiple processes with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel

Comment: Just calling 7za x (sourcename) -o (destfolder) -aoa

Comment: Are you going to do it "almost a million" times manually? I mean depending on your process there might be different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was not really 7-zip, but (likely) Windows Defender on Windows 11.

Attempting to split the large file into smaller archives and firing off multiple instances of 7-zip to decompress them led to identical decompress time, and a similar underutilization of the Disk/CPU. What did become more noticeable was that the majority of what CPU was used was taken by AntimalwareExecutable (aka Windows Defender)

In Windows 11, at least when signed in with a Microsoft Account, it seems apparently impossible to fully disable Microsoft Defender (whose active protection shows up as the process Antimalwareexecutable when scanning, but also involves other security measures). Even when you go so far as to turn off Tamper Protection, Turn off Real-time Protection, and enable the group policy to turn off Windows Defender... when you reboot, you'll discover that the group policy has been overridden to undo your change. It's possible that installing a 3rd party AV solution, then disabling it, will allow you to run without Windows Defender, but Ï did not test that.

Ultimately, I tried a test by forcing a boot into safe mode with command prompt. Firing off a single instance of 7-zip to decompress the files completed over 12X faster. From this, I conclude the problem is (likely) Windows Defender, or a related service-level process. If anyone has further insight, I'd certainly appreciate it.